Spring boot - content-type of request from controller set manually being overwritten
I have a pretty basic spring boot application where I need to passthrough a file - download it from a third party service then pass it through to the client.
The content type of the file is set in the request header by the third party service. I just need to retrieve it and set it in my response.
I have the following service:
public Flux<DataBuffer> fetchFileData(String documentID) {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri(uriBuilder ->
                        uriBuilder.path("/" + documentID))
                                .queryParam("TargetFileType", "Auto")
                                .queryParam("KeepAnnotations", "false").build())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);
    }

and the following controller:
@GetMapping(value = "/download/{documentId}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<DataBuffer>>> download(@PathVariable("documentId") String documentId) {
        Mono<HttpHeaders> fileMetaData = docuwareService.fetchFileMetaData(documentId);

        Flux<DataBuffer> dataBufferFlux = docuwareService.fetchFileData(documentId);

        return fileMetaData.map(metaData ->  {
            String contentDisposition = metaData.getFirst(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION);
            MediaType contentType = metaData.getContentType();

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

            headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition);

            headers.forEach((key, value) -> {
                log.info("Response Header: {} Value: {}", key, value);
            });

            return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(contentType != null ? contentType : MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                    .headers(headers)
                    .body(dataBufferFlux);
        });
    }

I would expect that the client gets an response with the content-type set by the third party service (currently in testing I receive "application/pdf" (I tested that I receive the correct content-type, and that it is correctly set), but the content-type that the client receives is always "application/json".
What is potentially causing the content-type header to be overwritten ?

Do you have your controller annotated as RestController?  If so, you need to instruct Spring as to which content types your method produces.  Add something like, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE} to your GetMapping.  Along with whatever other types you want to return.  Or, better yet, read up on Spring Content Negotiation
